# pandas.Series returning a Series when it should return an element

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I encountered the following weird behavior when working with a `pandas.Series` whose values are numpy arrays.

```
% s = pd.Series([5,2], index=[6,7])
%s.loc[6]
5  <-- returning a value of type corresponding to s.dtype, as expected

% s = pd.Series([np.arange(5), np.arange(2)], index=[6,7])
% s.loc[6]
6    0
6    1
6    2
6    3
6    4
dtype: int64  <-- returning a Series instead of a value of type np.array?!

% type(s.loc[6])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Same behavior if accessing it as `s[6]`.

Questions:

1. Is it even allowed to work with Series whose values are numpy arrays, or am I doing something bad to start with?
2. Is this a bug in pandas?
3. Is there an easy workaround, which works regardless of the dtype (e.g. also works for a Series with dtype=int)?

I'm using pandas V0.13.1

Comment: I'm not sure this should be classified as a bug, the same behaviour occurs in `0.14.1`, you've stored a numpy array as the first element with index value 6, so it's retrieved this value. Your output is a little different to mine, using ipython it displays this: `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])` which is what you stored so for me this is expected and correct behaviour

Comment: @EdChum are you saying that you see the same behavior *BUT* it is displayed differently? In my case it returns a Series, which is displayed as Series...

Comment: No I see it return a numpy array, what does `type(s.loc[6])` display?

Comment: @EdChum `type(s.loc[6]) => pandas.core.series.Series`. So the conclussion is this is fixed in `0.14.1`?

Comment: Hmm.. looks like it was, if you can upgrade and try for yourself then you can post as an answer, a lot of bugs get squished for every version update

Comment: @EdChum unfortunately I can't upgrade at the moment. You've been helpful. I still wonder if there's an easy workaround, other than upgrading..

Comment: could you try `s.loc[6].values` this will return the values as a numpy array

Comment: It's possible `.values` may not work but it should if its returning a series, note that this definitely won't work in `0.14.1` because `.values` is not an attribute of `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @EdChum, of course, but that wouldn't work in my first example (ints), which works as expected in the first place.

Comment: Could you tell me what `s.get_value(6)` returns

Comment: @EdChum `get_value` returns the array. That's a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Want me to post as answer?

Comment: @EdChum sure, your comments fully answer my questions.

Comment: This issue looks similar or the fix for this issue fixed your issue in `0.14.0`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this looks like a bug in `0.13.0` which is fixed in `0.14.1`:

```
In [110]:

s = pd.Series([np.arange(5), np.arange(2)], index=[6,7])
print(s.loc[6])
type(s.loc[6])

[0 1 2 3 4]
Out[110]:
numpy.ndarray
```

In the case where a `Series` is returned you can call the attribute `.values` which will return a numpy array, however this only works where a `Series` is returned and will raise an error if a single element value is returned.

As a workaround if you cannot upgrade then `get_value` works:

```
In [112]:

s.get_value(6)
Out[112]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```